# SQLAlchemy: An "all-inclusive" in_

Tags: sqlalchemy

In the usual Customer -> Orders example schema, if we want to get all the Customers that made an Order with order_category_id set to 12 or 13, we would tell SQLAlchemy to...

```
for customer in db.query(Customer)\
        .join(Order, Customer.id = Order.cst_id)\
        .filter(Order.order_category_id.in_([12,13]):
    # do something with customer
    ...
```

But what if we wanted to get all the `Customer`s, that have made `Order`s with both 12 *and* 13 `order_category_id`s? In SQL, I'd write it as:

```
select * 
from Customer
where 
   exists (select 1 from Order 
    where Customer.id = Order.cst_id and Order.order_category_id = 12)
   and exists (select 1 from Order 
    where Customer.id = Order.cst_id and Order.order_category_id = 13)
```

How do I trigger SQLAlchemy to generate this kind of query? i.e. one returning Customer entities that are associated with Order rows for both 12 and 13 category_ids?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
subq1 = (
    Customer.query
    .join(Order, Customer.id = Order.cst_id)
    .filter(Order.order_category_id == 12)
).subquery()

final_query = (
    query(subq1)
    .join(Order, Customer.id = Order.cst_id)
    .filter(Order.order_category_id == 13)
)
```

I haven't tested this, but I think it should work.

Comment: You should also be able to use `db.exists` or `db.[any sql function]` if you want to try that.

Comment: Thanks! In my code, I ended up creating a list of `query(Order).filter(...).filter(Customer.id == Order.cst_id).exists()` and passing it to the main query, as repeated filter(...) calls.